# Admob suddenly doesn't display

Tags: admob

I got this error.

> Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.

My app usually receives 1 million requests per day. But suddenly doesn't receive any ad request from 28 May.  I did't upload new version recently.

Answer (score 0):

"Lack of inventory" just means that there was no ad that was available to be served to your device. It is expected. Essentially this is a request with no impression. Impressions/Requests == FillRate.

To ensure that you are more likely to always ensure you get an impression I strongly recommend using Admob mediation and have one or more other networks that can fill any holes in your inventory.

What does your Admob dashboard say? Are you still receiving impressions for most of your other 1M requests? What has happened to your fill rate?